# Using MATLAB to determine root locus plot

Tags: matlab, asymptote

Using matlab (R2007b), is it possible to get the asymptotic centroid, asymptotic angles and the break away and break in points for a root locus plot and its jw axis crossing?

Comment: http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=ControlRootLocus ; http://homepages.wmich.edu/~kamman/ME360MatlabRootLocusAnalysis.pdf ; http://www.mit.edu/~6.302/notes/6.302rec8.pdf

Comment: So MATLAB cannot calculte them automatically for me?

Answer (score 1):

### As far as I know...

You simply translate each [corresponding formula](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Root_Locus#Root_Locus_Equations) into a MATLAB expression and write a procedure which includes the necessary steps.

There is an [`rlocus()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/rlocus.html) function in the [Control System Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/index.html).